# Why Object.getOwnPropertyNames() method returns only last pair property:value

Tags: javascript, object

Why does this method return in console all pairs property:value of an object, but for `document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML` it returns only the last pair property:value of the object? How can I display all pairs in my HTML file?

```js
var obj = {"prop1": "value1", "2017-12-14 16:00:00": {"prop2": "value2", "prop3": "value3"}};
var d = new Date(),
  ddPrev = d.getDate()-1,
  mm = d.getMonth()+1,
  yyyy = d.getFullYear(),
  hh = d.getHours(),
  min = d.getMinutes();
if(mm < 10) mm = '0' + mm;
if(min < 10) min = '0' + min;
if(ddPrev < 10) ddPrev = '0' + ddPrev;
var dOpt = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + ddPrev + ' 16:00:00';
var txt = obj[dOpt];

window.onload = function() {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(txt).forEach(  function (val, idx, array) {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = val + ': ' + txt[val];
    });
}
```

```html
<body><div id="myDiv"></div></body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hey! Can you put more snippet of your code

Comment: Perhaps you're trying to access the DOM element's attributes instead of its properties?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: the InnerHTML is a string! can you post your HTML too?

Comment: You are ***overwriting*** the `innerHTML` with each loop iteration. You're replacing the entire contents of `innerHTML` when you assign to it. Of course only the last iteration will stick.

Comment: @deceze is right you have to do so: document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML += val + ': ' + txt[val];